# 'PDFPage' (Enum) is ambiguous for type lookup in this context

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, macos-monterey

I am using the pod PDFGenerator which containes an Enum page 'PDFPage'

This is my code:

```
var page: [PDFPage] = []
```

Here I am getting the error, 'PDFPage' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context. I have imported PDFGenerator.

I got this error on running the code for first time after installing Xcode 13 and macOS v 12.0.1.

Is it because PDFPage is also declared in PDFKit?
How do I fix this error?

Comment: Write `PDFGenerator.PDFPage` or `PDFKit.PDFPage` to let the compiler know which `PDFPage` you want to use.

Comment: @Larme When I tried doing `PDFGenerator.PDFPage` ,compiler is throwing error 'PDFPage' is not a member type of class 'PDFGenerator.PDFGenerator'

Comment: How did you add `PDFGenerator`?

Comment: @Larme I have installed the pod PDFGenerator in my project

Comment: This was because I was using the name PDFPage elsewhere in my project. Once I replaced the Pod name to PDFPages everywhere, it worked.